# How do I update my firebase db with the following node tree structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to update my current firebase-db to include an additional child on top of the existing ones. As of far, everytime I try implementing using the updatechildren() function, A new child outside the existing one is created.

[image: Current firebase db]

My code:

```
nDatabase.child("unamrideshare")
         .child(nDatabase.getKey())
         .a‌​ddListenerForSingleV‌​alueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             try {
                 nDatabase.child(nDatabase.getKey()).child("Called").setValue‌​("Y‌​ourDateHere");
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
```

Anyone able to help??

Comment: What code have you tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: What I am really asking for is how to add another child within that db with a specific value, i.e. CurrentTime: "00:00:00" below CityName:"WIndhoek"

Comment: Hi Doug, I have tried the following:   
         nDatabase.child("unamrideshare").child(nDatabase.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                      nDatabase.child(nDatabase.getKey()).child("Called").setValue("Y‌​ourDateHere");
                    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }

Comment: I added your code to the question. For the next time you can do this yourself by clicking the `edit` link right under it. Having the code in the question makes it much more readable.

Comment: Also: in future questions please post your JSON as text, instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add another a new child within that db with a specific value, i.e. CurrentTime: "00:00:00" i recomand you using the following code:

```
nDatabase.child("unamrideshare").child("Posts").child(postId).child("CurrentTime").setValue("00:00:00");
```

In which `postId` is the unique id of the post you want to add the current time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: May I also ask how to update the CurrentTime value when a Button is clicked so that the existing CurrentTime value is updated to i.e. "11:25:15" instead of using a setvalue?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in the same way: `nDatabase.child("unamrideshare").child("Posts").child(postId).child("CurrentTime").setValue("11:25:15");`

Comment: Thank you. I am still confused by this, If setValue does the job well why is the UpdateChildren() method needed in Firebase?

Comment: Using setValue() method you can set the calue directy on the reference. If you use updatedChildren() method, you need to use a map.